# How to make a 20 rows x 50 columns grid in java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to make a grid made out of "." for a MineSweeper/Capture The Flag type game, but I've been having trouble. I'm trying to do a \n every 50 "." so it can start printing another column but my code prints a single dot every row. This is how the grid is supposed to look (ignore the % and the  since that's another part of the project, pretend it is alll "."): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX4Wb.jpg

This is my code:

```
 String grid = ".";
    int rows = 20;
    int columns = 50;
    int count = 0;

    while(count <= 1000)
    {
        count++;

        for(int c = 1; c <= columns; display(grid))
        {
            String nwln = "\n";
            display(nwln);
            c = 0;
        }
    }
```

My display method code per requested:

```
public static String display(String disp)
{
    System.out.print(disp);
    return(disp);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your `display` method?

Comment: "*[...] for a MineSweeper/Capture The Flag type game [...]*" - those are two very different genres

Comment: @Turing85 It's a game that the player gets put somewhere random in the grid and has to find a flag while avoiding the mines. Here, there's a link to my professor's game if anyone is interested: http://picard.sd73.bc.ca/.1230/g2/

Comment: "*YOU FOUND THE FLAG! YOU WIN!*" - Do I get a cookie now? :)

Comment: @Turing85 If I could find the flag I would request a beer instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's see a simple code to print the 20 X 50 grid:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String point = ".";
    final int rows = 20;
    final int columns = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            System.out.print(point);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

From there you can implement your flags and bombs in between the points.

Comment: Thank you! This is so easy I feel embarrassed. Now I'll try to figure out how to do the next part before inevitably posting here again.

Comment: You are overcomplicating stuff :) Think simple, if it looks to hard try to find another way.